# Can I fetch the prices of in-app purchases from my server?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Currently, my iOS app has to ask my server for the in-app purchase products available, and then afterwards, for the products, the app has to ask Apple for their prices.

The added delay for this is probably not much, but I'd like to make it faster.

Can I not use my server to fetch those prices instead of the client? That is, is there an HTTP-based API that I can use from the server to get the prices for me rather than the client? That way I can cache the results for different users and reduce the round trip time. If so, how can I do this? If not, in what ways are you handling this?

Comment: Why can't you just ask Apple's servers for both the available products and the prices?

Comment: @StephenDarlington In the server-product model you need to send a set (list) of In-App-Products out of which apples matches the one's present on their server & sends an array list of valid Product ID's.

Comment: @Pranav Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

****Client**-iOS App **DS**-Developer Server **AppleS**-Apple Server**

**Client communication with both DS & AppleS**
When the Client communicates with the AppleS you have a couple of advantages (as mentioned below) against a single disadvantage of time consumption.

1. When u send a set of In-App-Products to AppleS, it matches the
   one's valid & sends an array list of valid Product ID's (SKProduct
   Array). This completely eliminates the risk of displaying products
   which have not yet been registered, approved & cleared for sale
   against your app.
2. Localization - Price as an example. S'pose I'm selling a product
   in US & UK. The price for this product will be in terms of say US $
   in DS. So you end up showing the user in UK the price in US $. (In
   order to overcome this **only up-to somewhat extent** DS shall have
   a mechanism to localize the currency based on the user's country).

**Client communication with only DS**
To answer your question; Yup, u can use DS to fetch the price of the product. You achieve this by adding another attribute (price) to product object(from the list of in-app purchase products available from your server). Needs to be implemented at DS.

For Eg.
Product1 - in-app-product ID, Price, Name, Sample Image, etc.
.
.
Product n - in-app-product ID, Price, Name, Sample Image, etc.

Okay now how do we try to incorporate the couple of advantages from Client communicates with both DS & AppleS while using Client communication with only DS?

1 Adv - By manual check at DS end or through some defined process one can make sure that only valid products are displayed.

2 Adv - To incorporate this up-to somewhat extent implement the following @ DS

Step 1–Create a DB table at DS end having the [App Store pricing Matrix](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/13.0.0.9.9.3.3.1.13.1.1.11.1.3.5.9.1.5.1.1.15.3.3.1.9).
Step 2–When u hit a request from Client to DS, your DS can get the IP from service request hit. Depending on this DS service can find current country of User.
Step 3–Based on current country of the User, map the price in the localized currency from Step 1. In case current country of user is not a part of [App Store pricing Matrix](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/13.0.0.9.9.3.3.1.13.1.1.11.1.3.5.9.1.5.1.1.15.3.3.1.9) use the US$ price.(This is somewhat close to what apple does, though it uses country associated with Apple ID of the User).

End result localized price displayed in [IAP Confirmation Dialog](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT4009/HT4009_3-confirmation_page--001-en.png) will be same as price displayed by you (avoiding the mismatch as pointed out by you - somewhat again :-)).

This whole implementation will fail in a scenario when a user belonging one country has an AppleID belonging to some other country. It fail's coz DS maps price depending on location of user but [IAP Confirmation Dialog](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT4009/HT4009_3-confirmation_page--001-en.png) shows price based country of the user's AppleID (Mismatch !!!).

U can't [determine Country associated with Apple ID logged into the iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673351/determine-country-associated-with-apple-id-logged-into-the-ios-device). Check this Q&A.

I suggest you go implement 'Client communication with both DS & AppleS' model, however in order to reduce the delay associated when the Client communication with both DS & AppleS, have multiple product request(say a set of 10 products at a time or depending on how many products u display at a time in ur UI).

Only in case if you feel or more precisely have an analysis which say's you are bound to lose out revenue or the user because of the "delay" then go ahead with 'Client communication with only DS' model.

Comment: For clarity, in your example do you have the server fetch the price _from_ Apple? I think localizing the currency might be worth it as the price for doing so.

Comment: Not the server its the application that fetches the Price from Apple

Comment: But if it's the client app who asks Apple for the prices, then we have the exact case that I originally described in the question (which I'm trying to optimize).

Comment: So, workaround was to add a price (in one currency) against the Product in Your server. Are we talking about localization of Price at your server end?

Comment: Are you suggesting to have my server store the prices for the products (and not ask Apple each time)? What becomes then of the [IAP purchase confirmation dialog](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT4009/HT4009_3-confirmation_page--001-en.png).. I don't think my code can control the price in that alert (or do I?). I'm concerned about the mismatch in price as shown in the UI where I show my price (that comes from my server, as suggested) as well as in the alert dialog, if I were to consider localizing.

Comment: @YES on you server. The dialog N display price will not match if u don't localize. Please find my edited answer & btw u didn't ask abt price localization in ur Ques it's just that I pointed out a disadv. in my answer.

Comment: No @Pranav, the idea of localizing never came up to me until I saw your initial response (which turns out to be the real reason why we have to do it as Apple originally prescribed). So answer to my main question as initially intended: Can my server (not the client) directly interact with Apple through some API, and get the prices is: "YES, but only in US dollars (you have to convert)"?

Answer (score 1):

You could just have an array with the prices/data stored on your server in US$ and then localize them from within the app again. If you add more products or change your prices later then just update your array,  whatever its just one file sitting on a server. Of course the localization might take a while, I'm not sure if there is code to support it so putting in a dollar-equivalent for each country would definitely be time consuming but possible. End result would be much faster though, I have fetched my product ids like this and its UBER quick in comparison.

If you still get the prices from your server then have the app send the local through first and attach it to your request so that the price results can be localized.

Comment: "send the local through first and attach it to your request so that the price results can be localized." 

need clarity there, thanks.