# iTunes subscription pricing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, subscription, auto-renewing

I have a callback in iTunes which is supposed to make a POST request upon any auto-renewable (or other) subscription happening in the app (Subscription status URL).

The endpoint is functioning fine, and I can see what payload am I getting. Upon further inspection and decoding the base-64 payload for auto-renewable subscriptions, I can see there is no price being sent in the payload.

I did however see that in the response I have Apple ID and Product ID referencing my subscription.

Is it possible to somehow get subscription price from that info?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739379/can-i-fetch-the-prices-of-in-app-purchases-from-my-server

Comment: This is actually client-side fetching. I want s2s communication as I'd like prices stored in my DB when the purchase occurs